# Django request.method = 'GET' not working

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to load db table data on my app, in order to do an UPDATE on it, so far, I found out this is done by a `request.method = 'GET'` don't know if this always the case, but surely it is one of the methods to accomplish this.

However, my app is full of `POST` requests, to create new documents on the db table, I just need to retrieve one of these by specifying it's name. Using `'GET'` method. But it's not working, seems like it doesn't evaluates the expression, I don't really know why.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    id_proyecto = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #integer NOT NULL, CLAVE PRIMARIA
    nombre_proyecto = models.TextField(null=True) #text,
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(null=True) #date,
    existente = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s | %s ' % (self.id_proyecto, self.nombre_proyecto)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("id_proyecto","nombre_proyecto")]
        db_table = 'proyecto'
```

I'll use `existente` BooleanField, as a checkmark on my template, if this `existente` is active, then perform a query by it's `nombre_proyecto` field (project name) and bring the specified document.

My `forms.py`:

```
class ProyectoForm(forms.Form):
    nombre_proyecto = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    existente = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

My `views.py` where the method lies:

```
def proyecto_view(request):
    alerta=""
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProyectoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name =form.cleaned_data['nombre_proyecto'] #hay que verificar si el proyecto ya existe
        if existente is not None and existente != '':
            projects = Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name)
            ctx = {"projects" : projects}
            return render_to_response('scppp/proyecto.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        if Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name).exists():
            alerta="ya existe el proyecto"
            formProy = 1
            ctx ={'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
            return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            if not name:    
                id_proyecto=1
            else:
                id_proyecto=Proyecto.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id_proyecto'))['id_proyecto__max']+1
                nombre_proyecto = name
    else:
        alerta = "data erronea"
        formProy = 1
        ctx = {'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
        return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    sombra = "style=\"color: #a2a2a2;\""
    num = ""
    slash = ""
    quotes = ""
    arenas = ""
    fluidos = ""
    onclick = ""
    sombra2 = sombra
    graf = ""
    formProy = 0
    ctx = {'id_proyecto':id_proyecto,'nombre_proyecto':nombre_proyecto, 'sombra':sombra, 'sombra2':sombra2, 'graf':graf, 'num':num, 'slash':slash, 'quotes':quotes, 'arenas':arenas, 'fluidos':fluidos, 'onclick':onclick, 'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
    return render_to_response('scppp/proyecto.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = ProyectoForm()
    formProy = 1
    ctx = {'form': form, 'formProy': formProy}
    return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here `if existente is not None and existente != '':` conditional should evaluates if `existente` checkmark on inicial.html is active, if it is, render proyecto.html template.

The `inicial.html` interesting code with checkmark:

```
<tr><td>
    <span class="Sub-Titulo-Aplicacion">Tipo de Proyecto: </span>
    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="curva" value="checkbox" >Petroleo</input>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="curva" value="checkbox" >Gas</input>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <span class="Sub-Titulo-Aplicacion">Proyecto: </span>
    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="tipo" value="checkbox" >Nuevo</input>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="existente" value="existente" >Existente</input>
 </td></tr>
```

If this checkbox is active, render `proyecto.html`:

```
{% for project in projects %}
            <a  class="Contenedor-Texto-Menu"><span class="Text-menu" > Datos</span></a>
             <a href="/pozos{{num}}/{{id_proyecto}}/{{nombre_proyecto}}" class="Contenedor-Texto-sub-Menu"><span class="Text-menu" > Yacimiento y Pozo</span></a>
             <a {% autoescape off %}{{arenas}}{{slash}}{{id_proyecto}}{{slash}}{{nombre_proyecto}}{{quotes}}{% endautoescape %} class="Contenedor-Texto-sub-Menu"><span class="Text-menu" {% autoescape off %}{{sombra}}{% endautoescape %}> Arena </span></a><tr>
             <a {% autoescape off %}{{fluidos}}{{slash}}{{id_proyecto}}{{slash}}{{nombre_proyecto}}{{quotes}}{% endautoescape %} class="Contenedor-Texto-sub-Menu"><span class="Text-menu" {% autoescape off %}{{sombra}}{% endautoescape %}> Fluido </span></a><tr>
             <div style="overflow:hidden; width:0px; height:0px;">
            <form id="submitArch" action="/archivo/{{id_proyecto}}/{{nombre_proyecto}}/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id="cargarArch" type="file" class="Contenedor-Texto-sub-Menu" name="archivo" style="display:none;" onchange="submitArch()">
            </form>
            </div>
            <a class="Contenedor-Texto-sub-Menu" {% autoescape off %}{{onclick}}{% endautoescape %}><span class="Text-menu" {% autoescape off %}{{sombra}}{% endautoescape %}> Cargar un archivo </span></a><tr>
             <!--<a href="/graficos/{{id_proyecto}}/{{nombre_proyecto}}" class="Contenedor-Texto-Menu">-->
            <a {% autoescape off %}{{graf}}{% endautoescape %} class="Contenedor-Texto-Menu" {% autoescape off %}{{sombra2}}{% endautoescape %}><span class="Text-menu" > Procesamiento </span></a><tr>
            <a  class="Contenedor-Texto-Menu" {% autoescape off %}{{sombra2}}{% endautoescape %}><span class="Text-menu" > Reporte </span></a><tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is all the logic of the `existente` BooleanField, sorry if this sounds noobish, but this is an already started project and it becomes confusing at times.

If you have any idea about why this isn't evaluating that conditional plz let me know, I just can't figure it out .

Many thanks in advance!

PS = I'm using `Django==1.6.1` , Python 3.3.1 and PostgreSQL v9.0.

Comment: in views where is your `UPDATE` in `GET` ?

Comment: It should just load the data into memory, then show it on html fields, THEN I'll edit the fields on html views, or am I missing something?

Comment: "it doesn't evaluates the expression" . whic expression?

Comment: also correct your indentation in your problem, two `else` condition and `else` for `def` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the 'GET' conditional, it's like it's not there, I was using 'count' method to check if project name was already there, then realized that count wasn't letting me do the GET request, so I changed that to exists(), but still nothing

Comment: On else for first POST request, the other ones are 'nested' on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73721/discussion-between-itzmeontv-and-neove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of use of `filter.exists`. Need only

```
if Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name):
```

If query does not match any documents, it will return `[]`.So id doen't enter into `if` condition.Since `emptylist` `emptystring` refers `False` in python.

> if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists. It’s more efficient to use exists().

```
if Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name).exists():
```

If you want to `update`.Simply use `get`.

```
proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(nombre_proyecto=name)
proyecto.nombre_proyecto = "newname"
proyecto.save()
```

If you want to update `multiple` documents in the queryset.

```
Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name).update(nombre_proyecto="newname")
```

**Note**
if `Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name)` gives more than one document, Dont use `get`.Use `update`.Otherwise it will occur `multple objects returned` error.

Comment: Oh ok, ya, I see, well I just need to check if at least one result exists, so it's ok I guess, btw changing to "if Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name):" seems to enter in the if condition, but the if throws an "existente" NameError, not defined, weird...

Comment: BUT, if I use temp, it should accomplish the task without that if, right?

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be the right code, but it's not taking into account the checkmark, damn, should I open a new question?

Comment: Yeah i think. I will answer same there. :) you should delete this

Comment: Thank you! :), just testing a lil bit, I'll open it in a few minutes, thank you very much again!